# How to access protected variables in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to have a variable that will only be visible to its subclasses which is exactly similar to what `protected` variables are in `Java`.

I tried like this on the parent's implementation file

```
@interface ParentClass (){
   NSArray *_protectedVar
}
```

but unfortunately the `protectedVar` is not visible as soon as I call `super.protectedVar`

Correct my if I am wrong but I don't wanna use `@properties` to that variable since it will make that variable public.

And this is my subclass's header file looks like `@interface SubClass : ParentClass`

Comment: Objective-C is not Java.  It doesn't really have "private" or "protected" instance variables, only variables that can't be accessed because you don't know their names.

Comment: @HotLicks That's true of methods in Objective-C, but not instance variables, for which the language provides the following visibility modifiers: `@private`, `@protected`, `@package`, and `@public`.

Comment: @jlehr - Which can be circumvented.

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted declares an instance variable in an Objective-C *class extension*, and therefore the variable's default visibility is `private`. You can use a visibility modifier to change the ivar's visibility, as shown below:

```
@interface ParentClass ()
{
@protected
    NSArray *_protectedVar
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have this

ParentClass.h

```
@interface ParentClass : NSObject{
   NSArray *_protectedVar
}
```

Then just like how you access normal ivar, use `_protectedVar` directly.

But I suggest you use property with private header

Parent.h

```
@interface Parent : NSObject

@property id publicProperty;

@end
```

Parent_Protected.h

```
@interface Parent (Protected)

@property id protectedProperty

@end
```

So normal class only `#import "Parent.h"`, they can't see protected property.
But subclass can `#import "Parent_Protected.h"` and use protected property with `self.protectedProperty`

Comment: error `Use of undeclared identifier '_protectedVar' occurs when I did that

Comment: you have to put that ivar in main `@interface` .h file.

Comment: error `Method type specifier must start with '-' or '+'